# DataGridView To show cell content completely

Tags: c#

I am filling the datagridview with data and the data is not completely visible in each cell. How can I show all content which even has Enter Keys in it.

Comment: Please show us some code.?

Comment: DataGridView1.Columns["Message"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells is just resizing the cell horizontally with all the enter keys as special character in it. I would like to have Enter Key parsed properly and display it like Paragraph

Comment: The answer is not yet completed. I am getting ArgumentException for this when I use Fill. Could you please check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will diplay the cell content completely.

```
DataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCells;
```

Comment: for the sake of completeness, the equivalent for the columns width is: `DataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells;`

Answer (score 2):

Continuing from your comment above Try some like this

```
With DataGridView1.Columns("Message")
                .Width = 150
                .AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells
                .DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True
            End With
```

**EDIT:**

```
// Resize the master DataGridView columns to fit the newly loaded data.
    masterDataGridView.AutoResizeColumns();
// Configure the details DataGridView so that its columns automatically 
// adjust their widths when the data changes.


 private void SizeAllColumns(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(
        DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells); 
   dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill);

}
```

Comment: There is no difference between DisplayedCells and AllCells here. I want to parse the enter key in cell content and enlarge the cell vertically if it has more content and display it like paragraph. I am missing the readability here.

Comment: But I need to resize the cell vertically which is having more data automatically

Comment: I am using AutoResizeColumns after filling the data and after calling all other given code. Even after that it is not resizing.

Comment: You need to use `AutoResizeColumns()` after your `DataGridView` has data in it. That is the reason. Make sure `SomeClass.Table` get the data before you call `AutoResizeColumns()`

Comment: I have a function called upload. After calling this function, I am calling this AutoResizeColumns() at the very bottom of the code. But still it is not working. Any property we need to check for this?

Comment: Try calling that as a seprate method.

Comment: `dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill);` I think we're missing this

Comment: I am getting ArgumentException was unhandled. Parameter autoSizeColumnMode is not valid for this Operation. It cannot be NotSet, None or Fill but needs to indicate a sizing criteria